# 1d PDE's on infinite Domains using fundamental solutions.

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

so I've been confused by this before and i still have no idea.

> Use the method of fundamental solutions to solve the heat equation $u_t=Du_{xx}$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $t>0$ and the following initial data

For question a) we need to use

$u(x,0)=e^{-x^2}$

from my understanding of the problem i need to use the fundamental solution

$$\Phi(x,t) = \frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{4Dt}}}{\sqrt{4 \pi Dt}}$$

then the solution $u(x,t)$ is

$$u(x,t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \Phi(x-y,t)\phi(y)dy$$

the  issue is the notes i have dont explain how to expand or "solve" this in particualar ie in the above we have $\phi(x) = e^{-x^2}$

so we have $$u(x,t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{e^{\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4Dt}}}{\sqrt{4 \pi Dt}}e^{-y^2}dy$$

from here i still have no idea where to go with this ie no idea how to evaluate the above. any hints/tips of solutions would be great.

For the record i've yet to start fourier transforms or greens.

any help would be great. thanks!

Edit 2: the above example question came from a work sheet. The solution to the above is apparently.

$$u(x,t) = \frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{4Dt+1}}}{\sqrt{4 Dt+1}}$$

I dont understand how they came to this value.. what calculations were done or if im just missing a property which allows me to link the two. This is what i mean by evaluate the integral.

Again thank you for taking the time to read this. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "explicit"? What you wrote looks like a pretty explicit formula.

Comment: in fairness i was repeating what someone else said to me, though i just realised he ment when the Fundamental solution turns into a delta function, i apologise i'll edit.

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluate"? It's not clear at all what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Editted to hopefully be more clear

Comment: Ah, I see now. Still can't help you, but now I can see what your problem is, so hopefully someone else will come along and be able to help. :)

Comment: Thank you none the less. If its clearer to you then its clearer to others too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the result by a change of variables inside the integral.
$$u(x,t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{e^{\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4Dt}}}{\sqrt{4 \pi Dt}}e^{-y^2}dy= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{e^{\frac{-x^2-y^2+2xy-4Dty^2}{4Dt}}}{\sqrt{4 \pi Dt}}dy=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{e^{\frac{-x^2+\frac{x^2}{1+4Dt}-\frac{x^2}{1+4Dt}-y^2(1+4Dt)+2xy}{4Dt}}}{\sqrt{4 \pi Dt}}dy= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{1+4Dt}-\frac{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+4Dt}}-y\sqrt{1+4Dt}\right)^2}{4Dt}}}{\sqrt{4 \pi Dt}}dy=e^{-\frac{x^2}{1+4Dt}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{-z^2}}{\sqrt{1+4Dt}\sqrt{\pi}}dz=\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{1+4Dt}}}{\sqrt{1+4Dt}},$$
where $z=\frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+4Dt}}-y\sqrt{1+4Dt}}{\sqrt{4 \pi Dt}}$.

Comment: when dealing with these questions is a change of variable the usual method of evaluation?

Comment: In general it is very hard to "compute" integrals. Nevertheless  professors know that and in your assignment most of the integrals will be computable. That said, [gaussian integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) on the whole space are "easy" to compute and the idea is to change variables to get $\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^2}dx$. Since the fundamental solution has that $e^{-x^2}$ term you will always end up with an [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions) and integration by parts and change of variables should work